# Is there a way to use a glob_wildcard function on newly created files and use the function as a wildcard in rule all in Snakemake?

Tags: python, snakemake

I am building a Snakemake pipeline which clusters sequences and outputs a file of accession numbers for each cluster. I do not know how many clusters will be produced. I would like to generate a wildcard which can be used in both the input and output of a rule to process the newly created files. My toy example is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import re
import pathlib
from Bio import SeqIO

#Snakemake --cores 18

###########
# GLOBALS #
###########

TRANSCRIPTOME = ["protein"]

OUTDIR = ["outdir"]

def get_cluster(wildcards):
    checkpoints.cluster_csplit.get()
    return glob_wildcards(f"{OUTDIR}/Cluster/{TRANSCRIPTOME}-{{CLUSTER}}").CLUSTER
    
#########
# RULES #
#########

rule all:
    input:
        expand('{OUTDIR}/{TRANSCRIPTOME}.90.faa.clstr', TRANSCRIPTOME = TRANSCRIPTOME, OUTDIR = OUTDIR),
        expand('{OUTDIR}/Cluster/{TRANSCRIPTOME}-0000', TRANSCRIPTOME = TRANSCRIPTOME, OUTDIR = OUTDIR),
        expand("{OUTDIR}/Cluster/{TRANSCRIPTOME}-{CLUSTER}.acc", TRANSCRIPTOME = TRANSCRIPTOME, OUTDIR = OUTDIR, CLUSTER = get_cluster)
        
########
# MAIN #
########

#Use cdhit to the cluster seqs
rule NMG_cdhit:
    input:
        '{TRANSCRIPTOME}.faa'
    output:
        fa = '{OUTDIR}/{TRANSCRIPTOME}.90.faa',
        clstr = '{OUTDIR}/{TRANSCRIPTOME}.90.faa.clstr'
    threads:
        14
    shell:
        'cd-hit '
        '-T {threads} '
        '-i {input} '
        '-o {output.fa} '
        '-d 0 '
        '-sc 1 '
        '-c 0.90 '

#split the cluster file into seperate cluster files       
checkpoint cluster_csplit:
    input:
        '{OUTDIR}/{TRANSCRIPTOME}.90.faa.clstr'
    output:
        '{OUTDIR}/Cluster/{TRANSCRIPTOME}-0000'
    params:
        '{OUTDIR}/Cluster/{TRANSCRIPTOME}-'
    shell:
        """csplit --digits=4 -z --prefix={params} {input} "/>Cluster*/" {{*}} """
 
#process       
rule get_cluster_files:
    input:
        "{OUTDIR}/Cluster/{TRANSCRIPTOME}-{CLUSTER}"
    output:
        "{OUTDIR}/Cluster/{TRANSCRIPTOME}-{CLUSTER}.acc"
    shell:
        "echo {input} > {output}" #To be replaced with script to return accession numbers. Just renames the files for now.
```

I am expecting to rename the files using a wildcard `'{CLUSTER}'`. Instead I get a

```
"MissingInputException in line 63 of /home/js/Projects/cd-hit_2_fa_snakemake/Snakefile:
Missing input files for rule get_cluster_files:
outdir/Cluster/protein-<function get_cluster at 0x7f5ca2b07b50>"
```

error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look over the docs on checkpoints and some examples on SO.  You are using the input function like a normal python function.  You may be able to get this working by calling the function in your expand function `get_cluster()`.  You don't use wildcards in that function so you can toss the input arguments as well.  This may not work because snakemake gets fragile with how it handles checkpoints and I'd recommend refactoring your rule all to use an input function.